# Creating db connection for every page for single user in zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using Zend framework 1.11. I check all queries generated for every page using Zend profiler for every user. On every page database connection is created. I want to reduce total db connections.

For every user, i need one or few connections for every user session.

Comment: Since PHP is not running persistently, it will have to establish a new connection on every page load.

Comment: This is normal. And as you should be able to see from the profiler, the overhead for establishing a database connection is very low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting 'persistent' to true in your database params.

If you use application.ini, you shoul add:

```
resources.db.params.persistent = true
```

However, please keep in mind possible [after effects](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html)

> Please note that using persistent connections can cause an excess of
>   idle connections on the RDBMS server, which causes more problems than
>   any performance gain you might achieve by reducing the overhead of
>   making connections. Database connections have state. That is, some
>   objects in the RDBMS server exist in session scope. Examples are
>   locks, user variables, temporary tables, and information about the
>   most recently executed query, such as rows affected, and last
>   generated id value. If you use persistent connections, your
>   application could access invalid or privileged data that were created
>   in a previous PHP request.

Comment: And that's it? You won't mention what those are and why they might be dangerous?

Comment: Thanking for helping me.But will checking queries, i found "connect" as query. After adding above code.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, N.B., I've added explanation.